# How to create a side by side code box?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How do you create a side-by-side code box?

Something like this but copy & paste-able for each box and nice formatted without empty horizontal lines.

`1 2 3`             `a b c`
`4 5 6`            `d e f`
`7 8 9`            `g h I`

Can we have a feature request for this, please?

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you also gave a use case example. When would you need something like this?

Comment: something to show in this answer of mine https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169997/72456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The table feature is now developed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/703623)

| ``` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ``` | ``` a b c d e f g h i ``` |
| --- | --- |

Comment: Note that code blocks are not supported inside table cells. They may work, but there's no guarantee they will continue to work.

Comment: @muru I did use <pre>...</pre>, that is still apply for this tag too?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter how you got it, only inline content is supported.

Comment: @muru thanks for pointing that; that's fine, as long as they work it's OK and we can use it, but I don't think so we can see much table use feature in U&L's Qs/As, it makes posts less readable when editing. I just posted answer that there is something new added "tables";

Answer (score 7):

In the [answer you linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169997/72456), I would format it as:

#### infile

```
1 2 3 4
a b c d
# $ @ %
```

#### outfile

```
1 a #
2 b $
3 c @
4 d %
```